# Why would you make a struct without typedef?

Tags: c, data-structures, class

Since I cut my teeth on code with OO, I’m biased toward using structs as classes without methods. However, there’s probably a good reason that typedef isn’t the default behavior of struct. What is it?

Comment: What do you mean by "structs as classes without methods"? And what has a typedef got to do with that?

Comment: @amon `struct foo { ... };` vs `typedef struct { ... } foo_t;`

Comment: @Caleth yes but what does that typedef have to do with OOP?

Comment: What does the language C have to do with object-oriented programming?

Comment: It makes structs feel more object like if I’m only writing the struct’s name in the declaration.

Comment: @JohnnyApplesauce it makes no difference.  `struct` objects are just as object-like regardless of whether you use the `typedef` keyword

Comment: It was a language design decision made nearly 50 years ago. Is it really that unbearable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C doesn't offer custom namespaces as C++ does, [but it's untrue that C doesn't have namespaces at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3793976/15809). Functions and structures are in different namespaces:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Test ( ) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
}

struct Test {
    int field1;
    int field2;
};

int main ( ) {
    struct Test t = { 0, 1 };
    Test();
    return 0;
}
```

When you `typedef`, you are forcing structures into the same namespace as functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int field1;
    int field2;
} Test;

void Test ( ) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
}

int main ( ) {
    Test t = { 0, 1 };
    Test();
    return 0;
}
```

results in

```
main.c:8:6: error: ‘Test’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 void Test ( ) {
      ^~~~
main.c:6:3: note: previous declaration of ‘Test’ was here
 } Test;
```

Comment: Very enlightening!